# Why the number of vehicles are not increased in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I used VEINS 7.4.1 OMNET++ 5.4.1, and SUMO 0.30.0, I tried several times to increase the number of vehicles in Veins, however, the result of the simulation shows another number. I tried to increase the number of vehicles by *.manager.numVehicles in omnetpp.ini. Could you please guide me? I appreciate you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I read the below links over and over, so I understood that we can decrease the number of vehicles which is in erlangen.rou.xml 
However, how we can increase the number of them? the number of vehicles is increased when simulation time increase. As simulation time in VEINS is 200s, we should firstly increase simulation time then change the number of vehicles. These links are:

[About vehicle number in VEINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313470/about-vehicle-number-in-veins/46346676#46346676)

[How is the number of vehicles determined? In Sumo route file or in omnetpp.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765262/how-is-the-number-of-vehicles-determined-in-sumo-route-file-or-in-omnetpp-ini)

Answer (score 1):

The number of vehicles and other parameters can be tuned using the "flow" tag. For example, the period parameter can be used to increase the frequency of the vehicles, the number parameter is used to indicate the number of cars. So, if you decrease the period value, even for a smaller simulation time you can have a larger number of cars.

```
<routes>
   <vType id="vtype0" accel="2.6" decel="4.5" sigma="0.5" length="2.5" minGap="2.5" maxSpeed="14" color="1,1,0"/>
   <route id="route0" edges="-39539626 -5445204#2 -5445204#1 113939244#2 -126606716 23339459 30405358#1 85355912 85355911#0 85355911#1 30405356 5931612 30350450#0 30350450#1 30350450#2 4006702#0 4006702#1 4900043 4900041#1"/>
   <flow id="flow0" type="vtype0" route="route0" begin="0" period="3" number="195"/>
</routes>
```